# Fluent Assertions: Be() vs Equals()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

What is the difference between:

- `subject.Should().Be(expected)`
- `subject.Should().Equals(expected)`

I always use `Be()`, but I now have a testcase where `Be()` gives a different result, then `Equals()`. My testcase involves a struct and comparing it with the default of that struct.

```cs
MyStruct subject = new MyStruct("value");

Assert.Equal(default, subject);                  // xUnit Assert => works
Assert.Equal(default(MyStruct), (object)subject); // xUnit Assert => works
subject.Should().Equals(default);                // works
subject.Should().Be(default(MyStruct));          // FAILS!
```

Are `Be()` and `Equal()` the same and is this a bug in Fluent Assertions? Or are they asserting different things?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your results. How is your struct defined, especially regarding its default value?

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos It is not a default struct. There is some trickery going on the get a good default value. See https://github.com/DynamicHands/NodaMoney/blob/feature/improve-performance/src/NodaMoney/Currency.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Equals` method comes from `System.Object`.
You actually compare an object of Type `ObjectAssertions` with the default value of object(`null`).

This is not an assertion.
The method returns a boolean that is false.

[image]

Comment: Aha, stupid of me. So obvious. But then Be() seems to giving the wrong answer and I need to dive into Fluent Assertions code and possible report a issue.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. `subject.Should().Equals(default);` means your calling the .NET `Equals` method on a FluentAssertions object. This returns a `bool`. It surprises me that your IDE does not report that as a potential warning. `Should().Be()` will use the `Equals` implementation of your struct. And since you're comparing an empty struct with another one, it is expected to fail.

Comment: The issue seems to be though why the `Assert.Equal` succeeded in the first place. I, too, see the `Should().Be()` call to be correct.

Comment: The problem is with my own code. I'm using some trickery by swapping the ref of the struct (this) to another memory location. When you do that on initialization of default struct and check for equality at the same time, then the fields are still empty, but the properties (that wrapped those fields) do have values :S.

So `variable1 == default` fails, but first initialize a variable to default and compare that with variable1 works: `MyStruct variable2 = default; variable1 == variable2`

Comment: This is correct. Since FluentAssertions 6.3 this potential misuse of `Equals` is fixed. See changelog: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/releases/tag/6.3.0 and the issue: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1705

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that if you want to assert if an object (e.g. `subject` in your case) is the same (*not by reference but by value*) as another one (e.g. `expectedResult`), you should use `subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResult)`.